# Use << operator inside function arguments

Tags: c++, arguments, stringstream

I want to create a function that allows me to use the `<<` operator in argument and inside it uses the corresponding stringstream.

Something like:

```
/* This does not do what i want below */
void printStream(std::stringstream& ss) {
  std::cout << ss.str();
}

/* Desired function usage */
printStream("The number is: " << 42 << ".");
```

What should I use in function declaration?

**EDIT:**

Following Deduplicator suggestion, I'm trying to use variadic template. For my purposes, I've decided to create a template that takes a list of argument and returns the composed string.

This is the code:

```
template <typename First, typename... Rest> void getStringInner(std::stringstream& ss, const First& first, const Rest&... rest) {
  ss << first;
  getStringInner(ss, rest...);
}

template <typename First, typename... Rest> std::string getString(const First& first, const Rest&... rest) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  getStringInner(ss, first, rest...);
  return ss.str();
}
```

Unfortunately Visual Studio gives me an error:

> error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'std::stringstream' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   main.cpp    42  Test

The row with error is `ss << first;` in `getStringInner`.

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT2:**

I've found the error. This is the working code:

```
template <typename First> void getStringInner(std::stringstream& ss) {}

template <typename First> void getStringInner(std::stringstream& ss, const First& first) {
  ss << first;
}

template <typename First, typename... Rest> void getStringInner(std::stringstream& ss, const First& first, const Rest&... rest) {
  ss << first;
  getStringInner(ss, rest...);
}

template <typename First, typename... Rest> std::string getString(const First& first, const Rest&... rest) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  getStringInner(ss, first, rest...);
  return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Why not use a standard variadic template? You will have to use comma instead, but so what?

Comment: Take `ss` as a `const` reference because you're not modifying it.

Comment: Perhaps use an `std::ostringstream` ? What type is `First`?

Comment: You should indeed not use `std::stringstream`. It supports input and output. You only want output, so make that `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Ok I'll make the change. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that, it needs a preprocessor-hack.

Just use a variadic template and comma instead of left-shift:

```
template<class... X> void printStream(X&&... x) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ((void)0, (void)(ss<<x), ...);
    std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: Or just a few `std::to_string` calls and some `+`... :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Sure. But that would potentially have more overhead.... though only testing the actual situation will tell.

Comment: Right. I think the point I was trying to make is that this problem tends to breed over-engineered solutions.

Comment: The variadic template is a good idea. I'll check if I can use it in my real code.

Comment: I do use a very similar variadic template in my code base. You can throw at it anything that allows for stream output, including manipulators etc. It has the advantage over ordinary stream output that in the end there is only one output operation, which avoids overlapping output from multiple threads.

Comment: I had some modification in order to retrieve a string, but I liked this idea over the macro (that's good too).

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is difficult in C++ because the expression passed to a function will be computed independently; for example if `a` and `b` are integers there is no way to write a function or template `foo` so that

```
 foo(a << b);
```

does something different from calling `foo` passing `a` shifted by `b` (the compiler will look at `a << b` in isolation thus generating a bitshift operation).

What you can do is using the preprosessor, i.e. it's possible to have `foo` generating what you're looking for by writing a preprocessor macro.

```
#define foo(x)                \
   do{                        \
       std::ostream s_;       \
       s_ << x;               \
       std::cout << s_.str(); \
   } while(0)
```

this work by leveraging what is normally considered a limitation of the C preprocessor, i.e. that it works by textual substitution. The compiler in other words will be asked to compile `s_ << a << b`.

Comment: It's a nice solution for printing, but my real code uses the composed string to do something more complicated... I need to obtain a string that i can use in a logger...

Comment: I liked this solution, but at work prefer to do not use macros, so I've choose the variadic template solution.

Comment: @Jepessen: you can place whatever code you like in the macro. In our projects we use now a few macros like that (LOG_INFO, LOG_WARN and LOG_ERROR) that accept both stream-like and printf syntax, and that in addition also log the source file and line where the command is issued from. There are areas in which macros simply have an edge over templates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a macro:

```
#define printStream(arg) std::cout << arg
```

Thus when you write `printStream("The number is: " << 42 << ".");` it will expand to:

```
std::cout << "The number is: " << 42 << ".";
```

Which does what you wanted.

Comment: I think we can safely assume that the `std::cout` in his example was just a simplification, and that his real code uses a more eloborate output mechanism (e.g. writing in a log file whose path is configurable at run-time).

Comment: Actually yes.. I've a logger that takes a string as argument and I don't like to create stringstreams everytime I have to use it to print a message that include variables...

Comment: @Jepessen: for the purpose of logging calls, a good approach is to (1) create a class and supporting macro for picking up source code position information, and (2) create a formatter like the one shown by Christian in his answer, except with relevant implicit conversions to string types. This is **separation of concerns**, creating separate solutions to separate problems. Then you can use those solutions generally, not just with your logger.

Comment: And do forget about the silly macros presented in answer here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this without changing the call site. `"The number is: " << 42` is just a shift operation with a `char[]` and an `int` operand, regardless of the fact that the result of the expression is then supposed to be passed to some other function.

If you are willing to slightly change the calls, then you can use a proxy class that overloads `operator<<` and delegates the work to an `std::ostringstream`. Here is a basic example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class Printer {
private:
  std::ostringstream oss;

public:

  Printer() {
  }

  std::string string() const {
      return oss.str();
  }

  template <class T>
  Printer& operator<<(T const& t) {
    oss << t;
    return *this;
  }
};

void printStream(Printer const& printer) {
  std::cout << printer.string();
}


int main() {
  printStream(Printer() << "The number is: " << 42 << ".");
}
```

Comment: I almost upvoted, but then discovered that this places a requirement on the called function. That's ungood. In the time when I posted this approach east and west, the/my formatter converted implicitly to the relevant string types (also supporting various optimizations basically by calling a `to_string` function rather than using stream `<<` internally).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I happen to agree with you; I'd not use this technique myself for fear of over-engineering (I'd go with `std::to_string` and `+` until a more elaborate solution is actually called for, be it for performance or for readability). But I thought it would be a good idea to make the OP aware of this technique anyway. It may be a useful addition to his or her programming toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

what comes to my mind is creating your own string class, example `Cl_CharArray`, and to it add operator<< which would make a new `Cl_CharArray` from the strings left and right.

maybe using template will be needed. this task is fun, I will also do it sometime and return here. each class would then need a function to make it into a string (char array). I think at least one side (left or right from any operator) has to be a class, so it should be okay (that there is a number).